# MongoDB query for count based on some value in other collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a `configuration` collection with below fields:

```
1) Model

2) Threshold
```

In above collection, certain threshold value is given for every model like as follow:

```
'model1' 200

'model2' 400

'model3' 600
```

There is another collection named `customer` with following fields:

```
1)model

2)customerID

3)baseValue
```

In above collection, data is as follow:

```
'model1' 'BIXPTL098' 300

'model2' 'BIXPTL448' 350

'model3' 'BIXPTL338' 500
```

Now I need to get the count of customer records which have `baseValue` for that particular model greater than the threshold of that particular model in `configuration` collection.

Example : For the above demo data, 1 should be returned by the query as there is only one customer(BIXPTL098) with `baseValue(300)` greater than `Threshold(200)` for that particular `model(model1)` in `configuration`

There are thousands of records in `configuration` collection. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post a sample document from the collection.

Comment: Thanks for formatting. The collection is quite complex , I have just summarized the scenario

Comment: You can use a bunch of `$or` queries, but this problem is truly relational. If the data is huge and the data model really requires this structure, use a relational DB.

Answer (score 1):

How often does the threshold change? If it doesn't change very often, I'd store the difference between the model `threshold` and the customer `baseValue` on each document.

```
{
    "model" : "model1",
    "customerID" : "BIXPTL098",
    "baseValue" : 300,
    "delta" : 100    // customer baseValue - model1 threshold  = 300 - 200 = 100
{
```

and query for `delta` > 0

```
db.customers.find({ "delta" : { "$gt" : 0 } })
```

If the `threshold` changes frequently, the easiest option would be to compute customer documents exceeding their model threshold on a model-by-model basis:

```
> var mt = db.models.findOne({ "model" : "model1" }).threshold
> db.customers.find({ "model" : "model1", "baseValue" : { "$gt" : mt } })
```